# Get value of json with bash

Tags: json, regex, bash, escaping

I have json file with the following structure

```
{ "tool_first":"1.1.1","tool_second":"2.2.2","tool_three":"3.3.3" }
```

And I want to retrieve version from it with bash grep. I create something like this

```
cat myjson.json | grep -Po '"tool_second":\K"[A-Za-z0-9/._]*"'
```

which give me output

```
"2.2.2"
```

How to use variable instead of string "tool_second"? I want to have something like

```
cat myjson.json | grep -Po '"$x":\K"[A-Za-z0-9/._]*"'
```

where $x is the variable; x = "tool_second". I can't retrieve information from it with variable. How to escape variable properly in this way? I need just version number, without "".

Comment: Why parse `JSON` text with `grep`?, use a parser that knows the underlying format like `jq`

Comment: I know I can use jq but I want to do it without jq.

Comment: But why? Compare grep to the jq version: `jq --arg x tool_second '.[$x]' myjson.json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `grep` is **NOT** the right tool for parsing `JSON` text. Use a more syntax aware tool like `jq`. Use the answer below only for trivial purposes.

You are not escaping your double-quotes in your string to search present in variable `x`,

```
x="\"tool_second\""
grep -Po "$x:\K\"[A-Za-z0-9/._]*\"" file
"2.2.2"
```

and it can work for other strings too!

```
x="\"tool_first\""
grep -Po "$x:\K\"[A-Za-z0-9/._]*\"" file
"1.1.1"
```

Comment: Who/what are you quoting here?

Comment: It's not working. In best case it gives me list of all values.

Comment: @Tatarinho: It is working fine for me with your input json in question, can you post your actual file you are testing with?